# Azure Storage blob delete cache permission issue

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-storage-account

I have an Azure account with Owner permission for the subscription we have. I can see that two permissions existing for the same subscription, One is owner, and the other is Contributor. I am trying to delete the blob cache with the following Azure CLI command:

```js
az storage blob delete-batch --source <containerName> --account-name <storageAccountName> --auth-mode login
```

I am getting the below error

[image]

I am not sure, despite having enough permissions why I am getting this error. Please help

Attaching the permission of my subscription
[image]

My access permission to storage account
[image]

Comment: May you please take a screenshot of your permissions in Azure Subscription and Azure Storage Account?

Comment: I have updated the question with the screenshots of Azure subscription and Storage account @Andriy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `--auth-mode` parameter to `login`, it means that you use Azure AD auth to retrieve Azure blob data. If so, the Azure AD Azure AD security principal you used to login should be assigned to the role **Storage Blob Data Owner**  **Storage Blob Data Contributor** or **Storage Blob Data Reader**. Otherwise, you have no permissions to process Azure blob.

Now, your account just has been assigned to Owner, please set the `--auth-mode` parameter to `key` which means that users attempt to retrieve the account access key to use for processing Azure blob. The Owner role has the permissions to do that.

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-data-operations-cli#specify-how-data-operations-are-authorized) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad)

Comment: Thank you @Jim. this fixed the issue both in Azure CLI and Azure pipeline.